# How do I display thread/process Id in Python PDB?

Tags: python, pdb

In Python, is there a way to display thread/process ID while debugging using PDB?

I was looking at https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html but could not find anything related to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(pdb) import os,threading; os.getpid(), threading.current_thread().ident
```

If you need to do this often, it would be convenient to add an alias in your `.pdbrc` file:

```
alias tid import os,threading;; p os.getpid(), threading.current_thread().ident
```

Comment: I did not know about pdbrc. Thank you for the bonus tip.