# Switching threads within PDB

Tags: python, multithreading, pdb

New to PDB. Running PDB within Emacs. Python 2.7.12.

Followed instructions from: [How do I display thread/process Id in Python PDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39259805/how-do-i-display-thread-process-id-in-python-pdb)

```
(pdb) import os,threading; os.getpid(), threading.current_thread().ident
```

I ran:

```
 (Pdb) p threading._active
 {140313408587520: <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140313408587520)>,
 140313368295168: <Thread(Thread-2, started 140313368295168)>,
 140313359574784: <Thread(Thread-1, started 140313359574784)>}
```

Now, how can I switch between threads (in PDB)?

Comment: I set a breakpoint on a line of code that's executed in Thread_1 but PDB never stops on that line. The only breakpoints where PDB halts execution is those lines of code executed by MainThread.

Comment: There currently are no thread related commands in PDB. Work to change this is tracked in [BPO#41571](https://bugs.python.org/issue41571).